# Para que servem os atributos aria-* em HTML5?

Tags: html, html5, acessibilidade

Tenho visto, desde o lançamento do HTML5, diversos atributos `aria` nas tags HTML, como por exemplo `aria-disabled`, `aria-required`, `aria-readonly`, dentre outros.

Para quê eles servem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Eles estão relacionados a [acessibilidade da página](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) para pessoas que encontram dificuldades por alguma condição especial. O termo significa [Accessible Rich Internet Applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA).

Estes atributos dão melhor semântica ao que está sendo feito permitindo que os navegadores e softwares especiais (leitores de tela, por exemplo) ajudem a pessoa com necessidades especiais aproveitar o conteúdo.

Quando habilitado, eles são lidos e executam alguma coisa diferente para facilitar quem tem dificuldades. Pode ser uma explicação do que é aquilo, ou pode ter uma ação um pouco diferente para permitir usabilidade em condições adversas.

Curiosamente páginas mais simples costumam ser mais facilmente interpretadas por estas pessoas. Conforme o conteúdo vai ficando mais dinâmico, fica mais importante ter estes atributos. Mas é raro achar páginas assim, seja por ignorância dos profissionais da existência e necessidade deste recurso, ou mais raramente, por falta de orçamento e/ou vontade do cliente.

O principal atributo é o `role` para dizer qual o papel daquele elemento na página. O HTML básico tem a intenção de indicar os mecanismos que o navegador deve executar, eles são pouco ou nada semânticos dentro do contexto da página.

Mas só ele não basta. É necessário informar com mais clareza todas as propriedades importantes que o elemento possui para que isto seja acessível por quem não consegue identificar na página "normal".

Por exemplo, `aria-checked` indica se uma opção de um *radio button* está assinalada. Isso é importante para quem não consegue descobrir visualmente. Obviamente todo o código precisa saber manipular o DOM para atualizar estas informação de forma adequada.

[Referência](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/aria/aria.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).