# O que é ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications)?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Qual a função dessa tecnologia, como utilizá-la ou até, quando é necessário fazer uso dela ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Para que servem os atributos aria-\* em HTML5?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96948/para-que-servem-os-atributos-aria-em-html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**O que é?**

[Aplicações Ricas para tornar a Internete Acessível - Accessible Rich Internet Applications **(ARIA)**](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria) definem as formas de tornar o conteúdo e as aplicações web mais acessíveis às pessoas com deficiência. Ela permite a destacar conteúdos importantes na página para facilitar a navegação.
Por ser um conjunto de atributos especiais para acessibilidade, pode ser adicionada a qualquer linguagem de marcação, mas é mais adequado para HTML.

**Quando é necessário e como utilizá-la?**

A ARIA auxilia na acessibilidade, como alguns leitores de tela não reconhecem as novas tags do HTML5, é necessário uma informação sobre o papel de cada tag. Para isso, ele possui o atributo `role`, que possui um conjunto definido de valores para representar cada tipo de informação. A ARIA define roles abstratas (apenas para definição de conceitos gerais, não devem ser utilizadas), de widget (elementos de formulário, em sua maioria), de estrutura de documento e de *landmark* (áreas onde o usuário pode encontrar acesso rápido, como navegação, busca, etc.)

O [exemplo](http://tableless.com.br/documentos-acessiveis-com-aria-em-html5/) abaixo mostra o fragmento de uma página em HTML5 utilizando uma estrutura trivial de um blog. Com este código, se a página fosse acessada por um leitor de tela, o conteúdo não seria interpretado.

```
<header>  
    <div>Nome do Site</div>
    <nav>
        <ul>...</ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<section>  

    <h1>Título 1</h1>

    <div><p>Neste espaço pode ser inserido um formulário.</p></div>

    <article>             
            <h2>Um post do blog</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</p>
    </article>

    <article>
            <h2>Outro post do blog</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</p>
    </article>

</section> 

<aside>  
    <h2>Sidebar</h2>
    <ul>...</ul>
</aside>

<footer>Informações do footer.</footer>
```

Com a aplicação das roles nos seguintes elementos:

- **header**: `role="banner"`. Define uma região que possui, principalmente, conteúdo de orientação do site e não conteúdo específico da página.
- **nav**: `role="navigation"`. Define uma coleção de elementos de navegação (geralmente links) para navegar no documento ou em documentos relacionados.
- **section**: `role="main"`. Define o conteúdo principal do documento.
- **div**: `role="application"`. Declara uma região para uma aplicação web, geralmente contendo formulários, em oposição a um simples documento.
- **article**: `role="article"`. Define uma seção de uma página que consiste em uma composição que forma uma parte independente do documento.
- **aside**: `role="complementary"`. Define uma seção de suporte do documento para complementar o conteúdo principal.
- **footer**: `role="contentinfo"`. Define uma região que contém informações sobre o documento.

Com estas marcações, os leitores de tela poderão informar o conteúdo que o usuário irá encontrar em cada seção do código. Esta é apenas uma das aplicações do ARIA, que possui outras propriedades para permitir que elementos interativos sejam acessíveis e interoperáveis.

**Exemplos**

Os exemplos foram retirados desse [site](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/melhorando-acessibilidade-na-html5-com-uso-de-wai-aria.php).

**O elemento `<header>`**

Em HTML5 o elemento `<header>` pode ser usado mais de uma vez em uma página. Ele poderá marcar o topo (ou cabeçalho) da página como um todo, ou o topo de subseções da página, tais como aquelas marcadas pelos elementos `<section>`, `<article>` ou `<aside>`.

Se o elemento `<header>` marca o topo da página como um todo devemos usar o valor banner para o atributo role. Somente o elemento `<header>` que marca o topo da página deve receber o valor banner no atributo role:

```
<header role="banner">
    Conteúdos do topo do site
</header>
```

Havendo elementos `<header>` destinados a marcar cabeçalhos de elementos `<article>`, `<section>` ou `<aside>` o valor do atributo role, nesses casos, deve ser *heading*:

```
<article>
  <header role="heading">
    Cabeçalho do artigo
  </header>
    Conteúdos do artigo
</article>
```

O valor *heading* pode também ser usado em tabelas.

**O elemento `<footer>`**

Em HTML5 o elemento `<footer>` pode ser usado mais de uma vez em uma página. Ele poderá marcar o rodapé da página como um todo, ou o rodapé de subseções da página, tais como aquelas marcadas pelos elementos `<section>`, `<article>` ou `<aside>`.

Se o elemento `<footer>` marca o rodapé da página como um todo devemos usar o valor `contentinfo` para o atributo role. Somente o elemento `<footer>` que marca o rodapé da página deve receber o valor `contentinfo` no atributo role:

```
<footer role="contentinfo"> 
  Conteúdo do rodapé da página
</footer>
```

Dependendo da natureza da informação inserida no rodapé de artigos ou outras pequenas seções da página devemos usar o valor `complementary` para o atributo role inserido no elemento *footer*:

```
<footer role="complementary"> 
  Conteúdo informativo de um artigo
</footer>
```

**O elemento `<aside>`**

O elemento `<aside>` destina-se a marcar conteúdos complementares ao conteúdo principal da página, ou seja conteúdos não cruciais, mas suplementares. Assim o valor `complementary` para o atributo role é perfeito para esses casos:

```
<aside role="complementary">
  Conteúdo suplementar
</aside>
```

Referências:

- [ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA)
- [Documentação ARIA](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/)
- [Documentos acessíveis com WAI-ARIA em HTML5](http://tableless.com.br/documentos-acessiveis-com-aria-em-html5/)
- [Acessibilidade na HTML5 com WAI-ARIA Roles](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/melhorando-acessibilidade-na-html5-com-uso-de-wai-aria.php)
- [WAI-ARIA](http://www.acessibiteca.uff.br/?p=1252)

Answer (score 5):

O/A ARIA é um conjunto de atributos no HTML que prevê dar maior acessibilidade a pessoas com deficiências (motoras, ceguez ou surdez).

Pode ver uma lista de atributos [no W3](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/aria/aria.html)

Pode ver [o suporte dos browsers aqui](http://caniuse.com/#search=Aria)

Um exemplo bastante simples dum form com suporte a ARIA:

```css
[role="tooltip"] {
  display: none
}

input:focus + [role="tooltip"] {
 display: block;
 top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
<legend>Login</legend>
<div>
  <label for="username">Username</label>
   <input type="text" id="username" aria-describedby="username-tip" required />
   <div role="tooltip" id="username-tip">O seu username é o seu email</div>
 </div>
 <div>
   <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input type="text" id="password" aria-describedby="password-tip" required />
   <div role="tooltip" id="password-tip">Escolha uma password que se vai lembrar</div>
 </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Como pode ver o ARIA nao funciona por magia(mágica) é necessário fazer alterações ao estilo da página para realmente fazer algo que possa ajudar este tipo de utilizadores.

Veja também:

[Atributos aria em html5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96948/para-que-servem-os-atributos-aria-em-html5)

**Novo EDIT - como é que afinal o ARIA aumenta acessibilidade?**

Mais uma vez repito:  o ARIA não funciona por magia(mágica) é necessário fazer alterações ao estilo da página para realmente fazer algo que possa ajudar este tipo de utilizadores.

As vezes tudo o que basta é dar um foco maior, ou acrescentar uma explicação. Também é comum estas explicações serem numa letra mais percetível (fonte maior e mais legível).

Outras vezes estes utilizadores usam [tecnologia assistiva](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnologia_assistiva) tais como [leitores de ecra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitor_de_tela).

Ai quando você usa o atributo `aria-label` o conteúdo da `label` é lido para o utilizador. [Há software especializado para reproduzir estes sons](http://www.chromevox.com/).

Comment: Vlw a atenção, Bruno... Essa parte mais conceitual eu cheguei a dar uma olhada... Gostaria de saber onde e como ela é utilizada, qual a necessidade real ela soluciona...Tipo ela no código fazendo algo...

Comment: @MagicHat Completei com um exemplo

Comment: Bruno desculpe eu ainda ter duvidas, mas realmente não estou conseguindo captar o uso... Olho, olho, mas não vejo... Se ele ser para auxiliar deficientes, de que forma seu exemplo contribuí nesse sentido... O quero dizer é por exemplo, eu clico no `input` e ele mostra uma mensagem, onde está a acessibilidade na história ? Cara desculpe se estou sendo mal compreendido, mas ainda não consegui juntar os pontos :(...

Comment: @MagicHat Espero que esteja mais esclarecido agora.