# Navegação por teclado para acessibilidade

Tags: javascript, jquery, acessibilidade

Estamos desenvolvendo um site com acessibilidade ( apoiem essa ideia :D ), porém encontramos o seguinte problema. Quando criamos os atalhos:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>1</kbd>

No Chrome ele altera a aba e não vai para o valor indicado, que é o conteúdo. Nos outros navegadores funcionam corretamente, claro, clicando em teclas diferenciadas, como por ex.:

> Firefox = <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + número

O código que estou tentando é esse:

```
....
<a href="#conteudo" accesskey="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="ir para o conteúdo ALT + 1">Ir para o Conteúdo (1)</a>

<div class="container" id="conteudo">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</div>

document.getElementById("conteudo").accessKey = "1";
....
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso no Chrome?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160358/o-que-%C3%A9-aria-accessible-rich-internet-applications

Comment: Olá Magix Hat. Não sei se o conteúdo do post seria aplicado para minha dúvida. Confesso que não consegui acompanhar bem as soluções descritas no post.