# Como colocar ALT em uma Background-Image? Como deixar uma Background-Image mais acessível e semântica?

Tags: html, css, seo, semântica, acessibilidade

É uma pergunta simples, mas objetiva.

Sabemos da [importância da tag `ALT`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164876/qual-a-finalidade-de-alt-em-uma-tag-img) para a semântica, a acessibilidade e até para o SEO. Porém como eu posso setar essas propriedades da tag `ALT` em uma imagem que é definida como `background-image`?

Resumindo, existe alguma forma semântica de tratar uma `background-imagem`de forma a deixa-la mais acessível e amigável para o SEO, já que a tag `ALT` está disponível apenas para tag `<img>` e não para uma tag `<div>` por exemplo...

```css
.imagem {
  background-image: url(img/imagem1.jpg);
}
```

```html
<img src="img/imagem1.jpg" alt="descrição completa da minha imagem">

<div class="imagem"></div>
```

Comment: Em teoria, se é background-image não deveria precisar de alt, e vice versa. [Quando devo usar IMG e quando devo usar background?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190527/70)

Comment: @Bacco é uma tópico interessante, o problema é que em algumas situações para "enquadrar" a imagem de uma forma mais proporcional é preciso usar alguma propriedades que só o background tem. Ou até para fazer algumas animações onde usamos o background-position e com a propriedades da uma tag IMG não seria possível. Ai ficou a dúvida de como deixara o background mais acessível, pois nem sempre ele é só "decorativo", mas valeu a dica, a resposta da outra pergunta tem um ponto de vista bem válido, assim como o comentário que vc fez lá e aqui!

Comment: Aí realmente teria que ver o caso específico, pois esse "nem sempre é decorativo" eu considero um erro semântico, em princípio. Ok, pode ser um "erro proposital" no sentido de estar trocando semântica por funcionalidade, o que acho válido, mas desde que com consciência de que está quebrando a regra. Recentemente tive um caso de ter que dar umas "voltas" pra ter uma imagem responsiva proporcional, mas deu pra resolver com IMG mesmo (atuando na div embaixo dela). Uma outra coisa que pode atingir ao ponto que vc pediu na pergunta é por o conteudo textual, e usar o BG como "decoração ilustrativa".

Comment: @Bacco particularidades... enquanto as especificações não são atualizadas precisamos adaptar, tipo float:left pra fazer grid com div, ou padding pra controlar aspect-ratio, ou `<br clear="all">`, e tantos outros jeitinhos que precisamos fazer... Nem sempre imagens "decorativas" são background :D

Comment: Não estou certo, mas talvez isto esteja dentro das especificações: `<div class="imagem" role="img" aria-label="descrição completa da minha imagem"></div>`... [Fonte](http://davidmacd.com/blog/alternate-text-for-css-background-images.html)

Comment: @Sam acredito que o caminho vai ser por ai mesmo...

Comment: @Sam para tecnologias assistivas é sim, diria que é um excelente ponto de partida, mas precisa de algo pra pensar em indexação também. Tem mais de uma faceta nessa história toda (é claro que uma boa resposta vai abranger todos estes cenários).

Comment: @Bacco é vero. 

Comment: Me desculpe, buguei um pouco, mas pra add um alt na imagem não seria só colocar o title="texto imagem" na sua div imagem? tente isso.

Comment: @RenanOsorio apesar do atributo Title poder ser usado nesses casos ele tem algumas limitações quanto a acessibilidade... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title#Accessibility_concerns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `ALT` com `background-image`

Como citado, a propriedade `ALT`, tem benefícios, para o SEO, semântica e na acessibilidade, sendo um elemento utilizado na própria marcação.

Quando se utiliza CSS, não tem uma forma de adicionar a propriedade `alt` em um `background-image` e também, não é o adequado, quando se utiliza a inserção de imagens a partir do CSS.

[Segundo Christian Heilmann](http://christianheilmann.com/2009/02/25/so-how-do-you-add-alternative-text-to-background-images/), um `background-image`, é uma propriedade de valor estético, não algo com valor de conteúdo para o próprio site. Imagens adicionadas em CSS, são tidas como visuais, não são como conteúdos de uma página, portanto, estão isentas de textos alternativos.

### Outras Formas

Como o @Sam comentou, uma jeito de contornar isso e ter um [elemento mais acessível](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute), é utilizar `aria-label`, que é uma forma de especificar uma string a um elemento como um rótulo acessível, para uma tecnologia assistencial. E o `role`, apesar de ter algumas outras utilidades, ele pode ser utilizado para atribuir um papel a um elemento da página, ou seja, inserir um valor semântico a um elemento.

```
<div class="background-image" role="img" aria-label="blah blah blah"></div>
```

Uma outra forma de contornar, é adicionar o atributo `title`, que é um atributo para inserir um título a uma imagem, mas serve como um texto alternativo para o usuário. Porém, esse atributo em relação a acessibilidade, tem algumas inconsistências e problemas. Além disso, [segundo minhas pesquisas](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/image-alt-text-vs-title-vs-file-names/259441/), não tem peso de análise para o SEO, por se tratar de um atributo que somente vai dar um título.

```
<div class="background-image" title="blah blah blah"></div>
```

Existem algumas outras formas "cabulosas" de fazer também, como adicionar mais elementos para aparecerem juntamente ou sobrepor uma imagem caso não carregar, adicionar pequenas imagens (realmente pequenas, ao ponto não aparecerem) em elementos `<img>` com `alt` e depois manipular com outras imagens e algumas outras formas.

### SEO

Apesar de estarem em um [padrão de conformidade](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/aria/), dentro da minha pesquisa, não encontrei nada referente aos atributos `role` e `aria-label`, terem peso para análise do SEO.

A melhor forma de utilizar-se dos mecanismos de SEO, é adicionar a tag `<img>` com atributo `alt`. Mesmo com funções que algumas propriedades do CSS provê, se for seguir essas regras, de semântica e SEO, deve-se utilizar `<img>` e achar alguma forma de "contornar" e conseguir a customização necessária.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa visual apenas com HTML e CSS é usar dois elementos, o com `background-image` por cima e outro por baixo, esse último irá aparecer se o de cima não carregar

```css
.imagem {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.imagem-alt {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#img1 {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
  left: 10px;
}
#alt1 {
  left: 10px;
}
#img2 {
  background-image: url('');
  left: 170px;
}
#alt2 {
  left: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div id="img1" class="imagem"></div>
<span id="alt1" class="imagem-alt">descrição completa da minha imagem</span>

<div id="img2" class="imagem"></div>
<span id="alt2" class="imagem-alt">descrição completa da minha imagem</span>
```

Como mencionado nos comentários pelo @Sam, a parte de acessibilidade para pessoas com alguma deficiência pode ser feita pelos [atributos Accessible Rich Internet Applications](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96948/), porém não tenho conhecimento para responder quais deles devem ser usados e como implementa-los no exemplo acima

Com relação a indexação em motores de busca, o `background` não é indexado, talvez seja possível adicionar, também, a tag `img` e deixa-la invisível, mas não tenho certeza se funcionaria

Comment: Valeu como experimento, mas não considero utilizável de forma prática... Eu até tentei fazer um "gambeta" aqui tb rss, mas antes de postar vou pedir um feedback pro Anderson :D, Acho que a melhor solução seria como o Sam falou mesmo, ai só fica faltando tratar o SEO pro Google achar a imagem, pois a acessibilidade e de certa forma a semântica ficam em um nível aceitável ao meu ver...