# Atributo ALT dentro da tag SPAN é válido?

Tags: html, seo

comprei um template do wordpress que insere a imagem destacada dessa amenira:

```
<span class="fullimage cover" role="img" alt="O que significa sonhar com abacaxi" aria-label="O que significa sonhar com abacaxi" style="background: url('//i2.wp.com/www.segredosdosonho.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Significado-de-sonhar-com-abacaxi.jpg');"></span>
```

Porém, quando viu analisar o SEO do site, só alguns sistema identificam o ALt da imagem.

Devo me preocupar ou dessa maneira está correto ?

Comment: Acho que isso vai te interessar! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/341096/como-colocar-alt-em-uma-background-image-como-deixar-uma-background-image-mais

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, muito menos faz sentido.

O elemento `<span>` permite apenas os [atributos globais do HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) e `alt` não é um deles. Fora isso, aparentemente essa imagem faz parte do conteúdo da página, diferentemente disso não necessitaria de uma mensagem alternativa, que é o que o atributo `alt` define. Sendo a imagem parte do conteúdo ela necessariamente deveria estar em um elemento `<img>`. Colocá-la como fundo de uma `<span>` é o que chamamos de gambiarra.

Porém, se a imagem em si não faz parte do conteúdo e sim é meramente um detalhe estético, então não terá problemas em deixá-la como fundo, mas então a mensagem alternativa é completamente desnecessária - aliás, por que iria definir um conteúdo alternativo para aquilo que não pertence ao conteúdo?

Caberá a você avaliar. Se faz parte do conteúdo, remova esse elemento `<span>` e refaça corretamente utilizando o elemento `<img>`. Se for meramente estético, elimine o atributo `alt` do elemento. Inclusive os atributos `role` e `aria-label` também não farão sentido nesse caso.

Comment: A imagem é relevante, é a imagem de destaque do artigo. Não entendi porque o template insere a imagem de destaque dessa forma. Acho que o melhor é corrigir e inserir na tag img mesmo. Vou ver o que consigo fazer aqui. obrigado