# Como usar diferentes imagens no background-image, de acordo com tamanho da tela?

Tags: css, layout-responsivo, background-image

Estou otimizando um site e queria saber se tem como eu usar background-image diferente de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

Por exemplo, telas com largura superiores à 640px usar a imagem /referencia123/original.jpg e se for inferior, usar /referencia123/menor.jpg.

Só que não pode ser imagem fixa, pq é um site de receitas e cada receita usa uma imagem diferente

Comment: Se a imagem que você quer colocar em diferentes tamanhos é de uma receita, provavelmente [não deveria estar como plano de fundo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/341433) por razões semânticas